# IBM Integration Bus not generating xml attribute in JavaCompute node

Tags: java, xml, ibm-integration-bus

I'm creating a new XML document in a JavaCompute node following the instructions at [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac30340_.htm). The problem is the output is nothing similiar to the documentation

My code is

```
MbElement itemMaintance = body.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "ItemMaintance", null);

MbElement item = itemMaintance.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "ItemMaintance", null);
MbElement action = item.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "Action", "ACTION");
MbElement serialNumberFlag = item.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "serialNumberFlag", "0123456789");
```

And the output is

```
<ItemMaintance>
    <Item>
        <Action>ACTION</Action>
        <SerialNumberFlag>0123456789</SerialNumberFlag>
    </Item>
</ItemMaintance>
```

It should be

```
<ItemMaintance>
    <Item Action="ACTION" SerialNumberFlag="0123456789"/>
</ItemMaintance>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `MbXMLNSC` instead of `MbElement` as element type for XML attributes:

```
MbElement root = outMessage.getRootElement();
MbElement body = root.createElementAsLastChild( MbXMLNSC.PARSER_NAME);  
MbElement itemMaintance = body.createElementAsLastChild( MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "ItemMaintance", null);

MbElement item = itemMaintance.createElementAsLastChild( MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "Item", null);
MbElement action = item.createElementAsLastChild( MbXMLNSC.ATTRIBUTE, "Action", "ACTION");
MbElement serialNumberFlag = item.createElementAsLastChild( MbXMLNSC.ATTRIBUTE, "serialNumberFlag", "0123456789");
```

This page explains how to do it: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac67180_.htm